# jquery fancy box

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i'm using fancy box for some content editing in my backoffice. I recently added an image manager wich i create with javascript. It's kind of like a fancybox, but i had to do it from scractch for it to be able to overlay the first one.
My problem is this:
I want to have the user being able to press the escape key to close my manager, but if i use `$(window).keypress`

when i press the esc key, both the boxes close.
I have tried `$(window).unbind('keypress')` when i start loading my box, and i have tried to look through the fancybox js file, but it is minimized.

Does anyone know how i can disable and afterwards enable the escape key (during runtime) on the fancybox?

Thanx

Well I tried e.preventDefault() that i was forgetting, still nothing. I looked at the unpacked js file and i get this:

```
_set_navigation = function() {
            if (currentOpts.enableEscapeButton || currentOpts.enableKeyboardNav) {
                $(document).bind('keydown.fb', function(e) {
                    if (e.keyCode == 27 && currentOpts.enableEscapeButton) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $.fancybox.close();

                    } else if ((e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 39) && currentOpts.enableKeyboardNav && e.target.tagName !== 'INPUT' && e.target.tagName !== 'TEXTAREA' && e.target.tagName !== 'SELECT') {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $.fancybox[ e.keyCode == 37 ? 'prev' : 'next']();
                    }
                });
            }...
```

is this of any help?

Comment: The Fancybox package you can download also contains a normal (not minified) version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this works, but it's definitely a hack.

```
function closeImageManager(){

    $(document).unbind('keydown.fb');

    // Insert code to close your image manager

    $(document).bind('keydown.fb', function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.fancybox.close();

        } else if ((e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 39) && e.target.tagName !== 'INPUT' && e.target.tagName !== 'TEXTAREA' && e.target.tagName !== 'SELECT') {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.fancybox[ e.keyCode == 37 ? 'prev' : 'next']();
        }
    });

}
```

Basically you have your close function do the following:

- Unbind the namespaced `keydown` event
- Close your window
- Rebind the namespaced `keydown` event to the publicly exposed `$.fancybox.close();`

**Problems with this:**

- When `closeImageManager` rebinds the `keydown` event, it won't check `currentOpts.enableEscapeButton` or `currentOpts.enableKeyboardNav` because those options do not appear to be publicly exposed.
- It requires the repetition of the code that binds the `keydown` event (once in fancybox.js and once in the `closeImageManager` function).

Comment: that was really nice, worked perfectly, just copy paste and it's done. I understand how it works though. Thanks for the details.

Comment: Excellent! Glad that worked, because I didn't even really test it.